# Hide Console log on Eclipse based RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, product, rcp, console.log

I have a eclipse based RCP application.While running it as a separate process we are getting console log which contains errors infos and exceptions.Is there any way to hide/avoid the console log by setting any configuration parameter in the config.ini file?

Comment: How are you building the RCP? If you are using a x.product file what do you have in the 'Program Arguments' section on the Launching tab?

Answer (score 1):

Run the application without the program argument `-consoleLog` ([cf. Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html?cp=2_1_3_0)). This is usually set in the *run configuration* or *product configuration*.

Only by passing this argument should you get a console log at all. Note, however, that even if you don't specify this in your .product file, users may be able to "call" a console log by simply passing `-consoleLog` as an argument when running your application from the command line.

Also, I'm not sure whether third-party plugins or features would be able to activate the console log.